# Location of localStorage for Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

What is the path to localStorage of Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 7?

In web sources I found a path

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore\
```

but in my computer I could not find this folder.

Answer (score 3):

You should find it here: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies`

Comment: You will want to edit yoru post. %USERPROFILE% already contains C:\. But maybe you want to use `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies` instead, its shorter. :)

Answer (score -1):

be careful because i just saw such case, if you browse even with the display of hidden files and folders, you don't see the folder C:\Users{user}\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\, you have to type it manually....

Comment: I see that folder. You may not have applied your folder view settings properly.